# NoClassDefFoundError in Jersey from a locally installed jar

Tags: java, maven, glassfish, dependencies, jersey

I need to use a private Jar file in my Jersey server-side code. I installed the dependency manually and checked to see that it's actually there, then I've added a call to one of the Jars' classes, which was successfully imported by Netbeans. But, when trying to run the code I get the following error:

> Jan 07, 2014 8:59:42 PM org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder mapException
>   WARNING: WebApplicationException cause:
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: wrappers/ExtractFeaturesForGivenText

That's the code which cases the exception:

```
try {
        ExtractFeaturesForGivenText.main(param);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(AnalysisController.class.getName()).
                log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

and the entry in the POM file:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>featureExtractor</groupId>
        <artifactId>featureExtractor</artifactId>
        <version>0.8</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: The problem will be on your Jersey-side, more than likely.  Where are you putting the JAR that it's complaining about?

Comment: Since it cant find the defintion, you might be looking in the wrong place for it.

Comment: The jar file was installed by Netbeans to the m2 folder and then included (by Netbeans as well). I can also see it when looking in the Dependencies folder and when calling it from my code, the problem starts only at run-time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>featureExtractor</groupId>
    <artifactId>featureExtractor</artifactId>
    <version>0.8</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Since your dependency has scope `provided`, this dependency is supposed to be offered by the container (Glassfish in your case).

So either your drop the `featureExtractor` jar on Glassfish or you remove the scope of the dependency to attach it (the dependency) to your application.